# Can JWTs be used for a non-SPA website

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

Everything I've read about using JWTs for websites seems to imply they are for [SPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

My website has many static pages, but also needs user to sign in.  Is using JWTs appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by appropriate.

If you generate a jwt properly and store it in a httponly, secure cookie, that will be the same as a plain old session id in many respects (but it may be stateless on the server, with all of the potential vulnerabilities of storing state on the client, like for instance replay).

If you store it any other way than a httponly cookie, it will be less secure. A single xss in your application will then allow an attacker to steal user tokens. Whether you want to accept this risk depends on you, but for security-critical applications, it may not be good enough.

So in short a jwt is just a signed (but not encrypted by default) way of storing stuff on the client. A user or attacker cannot change contents easily, but that's it, he can read it, replay it, etc.

If you only store some kind of an id in it, it's not different from a plain session id (and in that case there is no point in using it). If you store state (session data), that may bring vulnerabilities that you have to care about yourself, like for example the risk of replay attacks, a user being able to find the signing key from the aplication and sign jwts for himself, a flaw in your jwt implementation, users being able to see session contents (as jwts are not encrypted), etc.